# "foop": a naming convention? It's a helper recursive function for "foo"; what does the suffix "p" mean?

Tags: recursion, functional-programming, naming-conventions, curry

I've come across the following code snippet (a function definition):

```
choose (x:xs) = choosep x xs
  where choosep x [] = x
        choosep x (_:_) = x
        choosep _ (x:xs) = choosep x xs
```

in [Curry programming language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curry_programming_language) in a "standard library"--/usr/lib/curry-0.9.11/Success.curry from [Muenster Curry Compiler](http://danae.uni-muenster.de/~lux/curry/). Here:

```
choose :: [a] -> a
```

and

```
choosep :: a -> [a] -> a -- BTW, not a _p_redicate
```

Is the **"p" suffix** for the helper recursive function **`choosep`** a known naming convention? Perhaps it comes from functional programming tradition (Haskell) or logical programming (Prolog?). What does it mean then?

(This function was considered in [Why is the non-deterministic choice function in Curry's std lib not defined straightforwardly but rather with a helper 2-argument function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5154339/94687).)

Answer (score 2):

In this case, I believe `p` stands for "prime". Rather than calling the helper `choose'` or `chooseprime`, they use `choosep`.

Comment: Yes, this seems to be plausible. `'` would be clearer than `p` ;)

Answer (score 2):

I think it stands for 'prime' -- in OCaml, which allows `'` in identifiers, helper functions are frequently named `foo'`. At a high level, I think this (and the use of 'where' for a post-hoc helper definition) stems from the desire to allow functional programs to resemble their equivalent definitions in pure math.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the Muenster Curry compiler also allows `'` in identifiers.

Comment: Yes, it's a very nice thing about names in these languages--that they allow to write primes at the end, so that it looks like math. I was glad when I saw it the first time when learning Haskell. And well, Curry also allows the more real prime symbols (`'`) in names, and there are primes in variable names in other "standard" modules' implementations. (Out of curiosity, I'll perhaps look whether there are occurences of `'` in *function* names.) So, the way to this "p" is somewhat strange: write out a `'` as `prime`, then abbreviate it to `p`... ;)

Comment: @Gabe: Path dependence then :)

Comment: @imz: Perhaps the only way to be sure is to email this guy: http://www.informatik.uni-kiel.de/~mh/ ?

Comment: True. Ok, if it's not a well-known naming convention, then I'll probably not bother.

Answer (score 1):

In this context, as others have noted, it probably doesn't apply, but there is a popular Lisp convention of using a final 'p' to denote a predicate.  See [jargon p-convention](http://catb.org/jargon/html/p-convention.html).

I personally prefer the Ruby convention of ending a predicate with a '?'.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! That's why it looked kinda misleading: a `p` sticked not to a predicate...

Comment: Ending predicate names with `?` is a convention in many Lisps (and some relatives like Scheme and Logo) as well.  Common Lisp, unfortunately, does not follow.

Answer (score 0):

P stands for 'predicate'. A thing that returns 'true' or 'false'.

Comment: That's what I thought at first, but in this case the function isn't a predicate.

Comment: Yes, `choose`'s type is `[a] -> a`, not a predicate. And `choosep :: a -> [a] -> a`.

Comment: Well, this is very interesting. There's a longstanding tradition of 'foop' as foo-predicate all over other areas, these haskellers are just odd.